# Слияние элементов кортежей множества

Tags: python, множества

Название не полностью передаёт суть проблемы, за что прошу прощения, но суть вопроса такова:

**Есть множество {(id, name), ...}:**

```
{
          (0, 'Акула'), 
          (0, 'Shark'), 
          (1, 'Кот'), 
          (1, 'Cat'), 
          (2, 'Тигр'), 
          (2, 'Tiger'), ...}
```

*Количество элементов может меняться*

**Из него мне нужно получить:**

```
{('Акула', 'Кот', 'Тигр', ...), 
 ('Акула', 'Cat', 'Тигр', ...), 
 ('Акула', 'Кот', 'Tiger', ...), 
 ('Shark', 'Кот', 'Тигр', ...), 
 ('Shark', 'Cat', 'Тигр', ...), . . . }
```

*То есть, нужно смешать полностью все элементы с разными `id`.*

Никогда с подобным не сталкивался, можете помочь с решением проблемы?

Comment: то, что вы написали `{('Акула', 'Кот', 'Тигр', ...), ` это у вас словарь или множество?

Comment: Это множество с кортежами внутри

Comment: А входные данные -- множество кортежей вида (id, name)?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: А результат -- перебор всех возможных комбинаций name?

Comment: Да, но с разными id (То есть, ('Акула', 'Shark', ...) быть не может)

Comment: т.е. получится по 3 элемента в результате, если отталкиваться от вашего примера? :)

Comment: Да, должно получиться множество кортежей с тремя элементами в каждом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, вроде бы правильно получилось:

```
from itertools import permutations

items = {
    (0, 'Акула'),
    (0, 'Shark'),
    (1, 'Кот'),
    (1, 'Cat'),
    (2, 'Тигр'),
    (2, 'Tiger'),
}

name_by_id = {v: k for k, v in items}
print(name_by_id)  # {'Кот': 1, 'Акула': 0, 'Тигр': 2, 'Tiger': 2, 'Shark': 0, 'Cat': 1}

names = list(name_by_id.keys())
print(names)  # ['Кот', 'Акула', 'Тигр', 'Tiger', 'Shark', 'Cat']
print()

# Определяем по количеству уникальных id
number = len(set(name_by_id.values()))

result = set()

for row in permutations(names, r=number):
    # Если количество изменилось – были повторы по id
    if len(set(name_by_id[x] for x in row)) != len(row):
        continue

    print(row)
    result.add(row)

print()
print(len(result), result)
```

Результат:

```
('Cat', 'Shark', 'Тигр')
('Cat', 'Shark', 'Tiger')
('Cat', 'Акула', 'Тигр')
('Cat', 'Акула', 'Tiger')
('Cat', 'Тигр', 'Shark')
('Cat', 'Тигр', 'Акула')
('Cat', 'Tiger', 'Shark')
('Cat', 'Tiger', 'Акула')
('Shark', 'Cat', 'Тигр')
('Shark', 'Cat', 'Tiger')
('Shark', 'Тигр', 'Cat')
('Shark', 'Тигр', 'Кот')
('Shark', 'Tiger', 'Cat')
('Shark', 'Tiger', 'Кот')
('Shark', 'Кот', 'Тигр')
('Shark', 'Кот', 'Tiger')
('Акула', 'Cat', 'Тигр')
('Акула', 'Cat', 'Tiger')
('Акула', 'Тигр', 'Cat')
('Акула', 'Тигр', 'Кот')
('Акула', 'Tiger', 'Cat')
('Акула', 'Tiger', 'Кот')
('Акула', 'Кот', 'Тигр')
('Акула', 'Кот', 'Tiger')
('Тигр', 'Cat', 'Shark')
('Тигр', 'Cat', 'Акула')
('Тигр', 'Shark', 'Cat')
('Тигр', 'Shark', 'Кот')
('Тигр', 'Акула', 'Cat')
('Тигр', 'Акула', 'Кот')
('Тигр', 'Кот', 'Shark')
('Тигр', 'Кот', 'Акула')
('Tiger', 'Cat', 'Shark')
('Tiger', 'Cat', 'Акула')
('Tiger', 'Shark', 'Cat')
('Tiger', 'Shark', 'Кот')
('Tiger', 'Акула', 'Cat')
('Tiger', 'Акула', 'Кот')
('Tiger', 'Кот', 'Shark')
('Tiger', 'Кот', 'Акула')
('Кот', 'Shark', 'Тигр')
('Кот', 'Shark', 'Tiger')
('Кот', 'Акула', 'Тигр')
('Кот', 'Акула', 'Tiger')
('Кот', 'Тигр', 'Shark')
('Кот', 'Тигр', 'Акула')
('Кот', 'Tiger', 'Shark')
('Кот', 'Tiger', 'Акула')

48 {('Кот', 'Акула', 'Тигр'), ('Тигр', 'Shark', 'Кот'), ...
```

Comment: Да, всё верно, спасибо. Удалю кортежи с повторяющимися значениями и всё будет отлично.

Comment: У меня вроде бы не должны повторяться элементы

Comment: Имею ввиду кортежи по типу ('Кот' , 'Акула' , 'Тигр' ), ('Тигр' , 'Акула', 'Кот')

Comment: Можно сделать так: `result.add(row)` -> `result.add(tuple(sorted(row)))`

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так же сделал